# Membership.CreateUser with custom fields

Tags: asp.net-membership

In asp.net i am using Membership where i have used 
 Membership.CreateUser(login, password, email, null, null, true, out status);
But I've the requirement where i want some more info from 
user such as Contact no and Short name

System has created tables for membership using aspnet_regsql.exe
But i've above requirement with more custom column

How i can store them

Do i modify those table but at a same time Membership.CreateUser has only limited entities
Please help

Comment: personally, I think you will find .net's membership profiles to be annoying and limited. Your best bet is to roll your own as @Jason suggests.

Answer (score 2):

you could use the asp.net Memberhip Profiles. but I find it to be very limiting. For my last project, I created a separate table with specific columns to hold the extra data. the PK was the username. then I would simply query for the custom properties.

```
var profile = context.Set<Profile>().Find(User.Identity.Name);
```

You may also want to take a look at the Universal Membership Provider. It's much more flexible than the asp.net membership provider.